# Copying table to different database in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, copy

I have condition where there are some table from one database (in mssql) which will be copied into another database. The copying time must be when a specific time, which will be given from application. In my case, I use Java programming. Is there any easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Agent Job in MS SQL Server that copies your data from one database to the other. Then in your Java app connect to the MS SQL Server and start the SQL Server Agent Job.

```
Connection rConn = //Your Connection details
CallableStatement cs = rConn.prepareCall("EXECUTE dbo.sp_start_job N'your job name'");
boolean checkvar = cs.execute();
```

You will need to connect to the `MSDB` database and the account you connect with needs to be in the `sysadmin` role or the `SQLAgentOperatorRole`

You SQL statement in your job may look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationDatabseName.dbo.DestinationTable (ColumnNames)

SELECT YourColumns
FROM   SourceDatabaseName.dbo.SourceTable
```